# Regex code for address separated by commas

Tags: regex

How can I extract the state text which is before third comma only using the regex code?

> `54 West 21st Street Suite 603, New York,`**New York**,`United States, 10010`

I've managed to extract the rest how I wanted but this one is a problem.

Also, how can I extract the "United States" please?

Comment: Why don't you split by comma?

Comment: You've provided limited information. As @Jerry mentioned, why not use a Split function? Likewise can you guarantee your data model will always be the same (think internationally or PO Box)? Regarding RegEx specifically you could always use a count method to find the position of the 2nd & 3rd commas and capture what's in between with an InStr or Substring function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you want to use capturing groups:

```
.*,.*,(.*),(.*),.*
```

The first capturing group will be "New York" and the second will be "United States" ([try it](http://rubular.com/r/p7aGSbm4iq) on Rubular).

Or you can split by commas (which will probably be even simpler) as @Jerry [points out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18387557/regex-code-for-adress-separated-by-commas#comment27003646_18387557), assuming the language/tool you're using supports that.

Comment: Thank you, I wanted to avoid separation by comma because of my software, this works great.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this regex:

```
(?:[^,]*,){2}([^,]*)
```

And use captured group # 1 for your desired String.

Comment: Depending on the engine, the first group is likely to be too greedy. YMMV.

Comment: @CodeGnome: I am really not aware for which regex engine `(?:[^,]*,)` won't work.

Comment: Your regex certainly works in Ruby. I haven't tested it on other engines; my point was really just that greedy expressions can be troublesome, rather than a criticism of the specific regex you posted. See my answer for a case where forgetting the lazy quantifier would yield the wrong result.

Comment: Which part of my regex do you believe is greedy?

Comment: `*` is a greedy quantifier, while `*?` is lazy. In your specific case, I'm not sure it matters because of the OP's limited corpus. However, consider the difference between `',,,,,'.match /,*,/` and `',,,,,'.match /,*?,/`. --This is starting to slide out of scope of the question, so I'll leave it there. I'm mostly just trying to help future visitors avoid problems as they try to adapt the solution, so feel free to ignore my comments if you don't think they're relevant.

Comment: First of all I don't mind any meaningful/sincere comments. Coming back to greedy-ness `[^,]*` is actually not greedy since it uses negation to match 0 or more characters until it gets a comma. My suggested solution worked perfectly fine with `',,,,,'.match(/(?:[^,]*,){2}([^,]*)/)`

Answer (score 0):

### TL;DR

A lot depends on your regular expression engine, and whether you really need a regular expression or field-splitting. You can do field-splitting in Ruby and Awk (among others), but sed and grep only do regular expressions. See some examples below to get you started.

### Ruby

```
str = '54 West 21st Street Suite 603, New York,New York,United States, 10010'
str.match /(?:.*?,){2}([^,]+)/
$1
#=> "New York"
```

### GNU sed

```
$ echo '54 West 21st Street Suite 603, New York,New York,United States, 10010' |
    sed -rn 's/([^,]+,){2}([^,]+).*/\2/p'
```

### GNU awk

```
$ echo '54 West 21st Street Suite 603, New York,New York,United States, 10010' |
    awk -F, '{print $3}'
```